# Converting 2nd order differential equation to state space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got two 2nd order differential equations that I need to convert to state space in order to express them as first order ODE's to model something in Matlab (using ODE45, for what it's worth). They are:

$$\ddot \theta= \frac{-2 \dot r \dot \theta}{r} -\frac {g \cdot \sin(\theta)}{r} - \frac{B}{m} \sqrt{\dot r^2 + r^2\dot\theta^2}  $$

$$  \ddot r = g\cdot \cos(\theta) - \frac{k}{m}(r-R)- \frac{B\dot r}{m}\sqrt{\dot r^2 + r^2\dot\theta^2}    $$

$B$, $m$, $k$, $g$, and $R$ are constants.

How I've attempted to do this:
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
        r_1\\
        r_2\\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        r\\
        \dot r\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
        \theta_1\\
        \theta_2\\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \theta\\
        \dot \theta\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Taking the derivatives of these, I got:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        \dot r_1\\
        \dot r_2\\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot r\\
        \ddot r\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
        \dot \theta_1\\
        \dot \theta_2\\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot \theta\\
        \ddot \theta\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

So,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
        \dot \theta_1\\
        \dot \theta_2\\
        \dot r_1\\
        \dot r_2\\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot \theta\\
        \frac{-2 \dot r \dot \theta}{r} -\frac {g \cdot \sin(\theta)}{r} - \frac{B}{m} \sqrt{\dot r^2 + r^2\dot\theta^2} \\
        \dot r\\
        g\cdot \cos(\theta) - \frac{k}{m}(r-R)- \frac{B\dot r}{m}\sqrt{\dot r^2 + r^2\dot\theta^2}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

This may be the right answer, but when I provide initial conditions and attempt to model this in Matlab, I get a wacky looking plot that doesn't make much sense.

Did I go wrong anywhere in here? Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: You might find [this blog post from the MathWorks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/06/10/from-symbolic-differential-equations-to-their-numeric-solution/) helpful, though it's good to be able to do this yourself and you're nearly there.

Answer (score 1):

On the right hand side you have $\theta$, $\dot\theta$, $r$ and $\dot r$. They should be $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $r_1$ and $r_2$.